# C++ Error while passing enum as default parameter by reference in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class Schedule
{
    public:
    enum day{MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};
    void isWeekend(day &dayOfWeek=SUN);
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the day in the function that calls `isWeekend`, defaulting it to 'SUN'.
On VS2017, this is the error that I see:

```
initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue.
```

What am I missing? 
The same function compiles without the `&` i.e.

```
void isWeekend(day dayOfWeek=SUN)
```

Comment: `SUN` is not a reference to a `day` value. You can't set the default value of some pointer to be anything other than a pointer to the same type, and you can't set the default value of a reference to something that's not a reference (setting aside `const`-qualifiers, for now).

Comment: Exactly what the error says. What exactly do you have trouble with?

Comment: `void isWeekend(day const &dayOfWeek=SUN);`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik are you positive that you can't initialize a reference with a non-reference? Because there's quite the chicken-and-egg problem then ;)

Comment: @Quentin: This is the exact error: error C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'day' to 'day &'

Comment: @liliscent: if I specify it as const, I won't be able to change the value of the 'dayOfWeek' variable inside the isWeekend function. I need that functionality.

Comment: Ah, but what variable would you be changing here exactly? `SUN` is a value, not a variable.

Comment: `void isWeekend(day &dayOfWeek=SUN);` shouldn't a function named this return a bool and be const? I mean I would expect this signature: `bool isWeekend(const day & dayOfWeek=SUN) const;`

Comment: @storyTeller: Let's say there are 2 functions:

void funcA
{
 ...
isWeekend();
}

void funcB
{
 day d;
isWeekend(d);
}

isWeekend should be able to change the value of 'd' being passed in the function. If isWeekend is called without any arguments, then SUN is used by default by the calling function.

Comment: And I just told you... SUN is not an object, it's a value.

Comment: @drescherjm That's exactly how my actual function signature looks like: bool as the return type and is a const func.I skipped this information because isWeekend is an example function written only for the purposes of asking the question here.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks a lot for your reply. I think I'm understanding what you're trying to tell me. For instance, this compiles: void isWeekday(std::string& dayOfWeek=std::string("sunday")); while this does not: void isWeekday(std::string& dayOfWeek="sunday"); Question is, how do I do the same i.e. create an object for an enum? I've tried a few things but I'm messing up the syntax somewhere and am getting an error.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are declaring the parameter to be a non-const lvalue reference (as the error message suggests). An lvalue is essentially something that can be assigned to, so an lvalue reference is a reference to an existing object. *SUN* here, thus, is not an lvalue and therefore cannot be used to initialize the lvalue reference. A caller would have to call this method with an existing variable as its parameter if you declare it to be an lvalue reference. So remove the reference, since it's not necessary here if this is just supposed to be an input parameter.

See here for more information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: Your entire explanation doesn't add up to why making it `const` is suddenly okay

Comment: You're right and it's not necessary here anyway. I edited my answer.

Comment: Well, better. Though I was hoping you'd instead elaborate on why const makes a difference. Make the answer more informative and all that. But this is good too.

Comment: @MatthiasGrün: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I understood the mistake, though I'm still figuring out how to fix it. I can't lose the '&' because I want the isWeekday() to be able to change the value of the parameter passed. Thanks again though.